# Set Product as New from Date - Reverts to random date in past after clicking out of product edit

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, filter, date

We have an issue with using New From Date as filter in product grid

*Steps*
- on admin go to products > catalog 
- in columns make sure you have 'set product as new from date' selected
- in filters apply a date range in new from date 
- click into a product and save and close

*expected result:*
- inputted data in filter fields remains the same

*actual result:*
- inputted data in date fields changes to one in the past, though the results seem to be correct.

[image]
Not sure if this is a M2 bug, has anyone experienced it or try to replicate?

### UPDATE

So it seems there is a problem with this function

```
dateFormat = this.shiftedValue() ? this.outputDateFormat : this.inputDateFormat;

 /**
     * Prepares and sets date/time value that will be displayed
     * in the input field.
     *
     * @param {String} value
     */
    onValueChange: function (value) {
        var dateFormat,
            shiftedValue;

        if (value) {
            if (this.options.showsTime) {
                shiftedValue = moment.tz(value, 'UTC').tz(this.storeTimeZone);
            } else {
                dateFormat = this.shiftedValue() ? this.outputDateFormat : this.inputDateFormat;

                shiftedValue = moment(value, dateFormat);
            }

            shiftedValue = shiftedValue.format(this.pickerDateTimeFormat);
        } else {
            shiftedValue = '';
        }

        if (shiftedValue !== this.shiftedValue()) {
            this.shiftedValue(shiftedValue);
        }
    },
```

seems it's not able to retrieve the shiftedValue so it uses `this.inputDateFormat (YYYY-MM-DD)` instead of `this.outoutDateFormat (MM/DD/YYYY)`

replacing it as

```
dateFormat = this.shiftedValue() ? this.outputDateFormat : this.outputDateFormat;
```

works.

Any idea to fix properly the bug?

Answer (score 0):

this workaround in `date.js` fixed our case

```
var dateRegexp='(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \\/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \\/.](19|20)\\d\\d';`

if (value.match(dateRegexp)){
  dateFormat='MM/DD/YYYY';
}
```